# PHP : Not able to show retrieved value from database into dropdown which is assigned a php variable

Tags: php

I have a dropdown in a form, which has got a variable which contains values from database.

```
<b>Assignee: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </b><select name = "assignee" id="assignee" value = <?php echo $dropdown ?></select> &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp
```

so Assignee dropdown will be populated from database, for which the values are stored in $dropdown.

Now after i submit the form. There is an edit button. So when user clicks the button. The form should populate the same value which has been used for submission. But currently its populating the default values.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for a html select dropdown is as following

```
<select name="form_name">
    <option value="test">foo</option>
    <option value="tests" selected>sfoo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yes i understood but here the option values are pased from a php variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   include('configdb.php');
   $query = "SELECT username FROM users";
   $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
   $dropdown = '\r\n';
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $dropdown .= "<option width='200' value='".$row['username']."'>".$row['username']."/option>";
   }
   $dropdown .= "\r\n";
  <b>Assignee:</b>
  <select name = "assignee" id="assignee"><?php echo $dropdown; ?></select>
```

Comment: @harishmahesh - what is the value of $dropdown?

Comment: dropdown list all the usernames in a select box.
  
  code is :
  
     <?php
include('configdb.php');
    $query = "SELECT username FROM users";

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $assignee = "<select name='user'> width = '200'";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $dropdown .= "\r\n<option width = '200'  value='{$row['username']}'>{$row['username']}</option>";
    }
    $dropdown .= "\r\n</select> ";
    
    ?> 
    Assignee:</b><select name = "assignee" id="assignee" value = <?php echo $dropdown ?></select>

Comment: But when I click edit, the Assignee name which is saved is not populated, instead the default value is shown. I need to get for which username its been saved.

Comment: Now, iam getting the usernames populated as name/option>. Also the saved name is not populated.